# Grouping of polygons or overlaying layers in same shapefile? Problems calculating the correct polygon areas

Tags: qgis, polygon, area

I am having trouble calculating polygon areas of my shapefile. When opening the shapefile in QGIS it seems like there are multiple polygons overlapping within the same shapefile or that polygon areas are grouped together somehow. Then when calculating area with $area, this gives too large areas. What I want to calculate is the area of all the black smaller polygons seperately and not the red somehow "grouped" polygons.

[image]

For clarification, CRS of the shapefile is: EPSG:32630 - WGS 84 / UTM zone 30N - Projected (unit is meters).
I have already tried to fix invalid geometry following this guide: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/handling_invalid_geometries.html . But it did not change the way the polygon areas are calculated.

Comment: Have you tried the tools `multi- to single-part` and `remove duplicate geometries`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I have tried what you suggested but this does not return the small single polygons (black line) that I need to calculate areas of but groups them in the larger polygons (red line). After applying "delete duplicate geometries" I still get too large areas and total area.